# Passing multiple model in ModelAndView and Iterating those models

Tags: java, model-view-controller, apache-poi, poi-hssf, modelandview

I have a requirement where I have to write HSSfWorkbook with multiple HSSfSheets.
For first sheet I have different columns and second sheet has different set of columns. For each sheet I have different stored procedure written. 
Currently my java code is written in a way which can handle only one stored procedure data. I want to modify it and call second stored procedure to populate data in second sheet. I am setting the excel bean data in ModelAndView object and building the document. Now my question is how to fetch the each model and write it in HSSfSheet? Like in controller I am setting two beans in map downloadExcelBean and downloadExcelBean2. I want to write downloadExcelBean in first sheet and downloadExcelBean2 in second sheet. Please suggest.
        My controller function is as below.

```
     public ModelAndView exportToExcel(String fileName1, String filename2,String sheetname1,String sheetName2,
        String[] headerLabels1, String[] headerLabels2,int[] datatypeArray1,int[] datatypeArray2, String procString1,String procString2,
        Object[] objarray, HttpServletRequest arg0,
        HttpServletResponse arg1, String[] dbColumnNameArray1,String[] dbColumnNameArray2)
        throws Exception {
    Log.info(DownloadExcelController.class,
            "Execution Starts..exportExcel()");

    Map<String, DownloadExcelBean> downloadExcelBean = new HashMap<String, DownloadExcelBean>();
    //System.out.println(" in export excel part....."+procString+":::"+datatypeArray);
    List<List> workLists1 = downloadExcelService.storedProcedureToExcel(
            datatypeArray1, procString1, objarray, dbColumnNameArray1);

    List<List> workLists2 = downloadExcelService.storedProcedureToExcel(
            datatypeArray2, procString2, objarray, dbColumnNameArray2);

    DownloadExcelBean bean = new DownloadExcelBean();

    bean.setFilename(fileName1);
    bean.setSheetname(sheetname1);
    bean.setHeaderArray(headerLabels1);
    bean.setDatatypeArray(datatypeArray1);
    // bean.setVisibleArray(visibleArray);

    bean.setData(workLists1);

    DownloadExcelBean bean2 = new DownloadExcelBean();
    bean2.setFilename(filename2);
    bean2.setSheetname(sheetName2);
    bean2.setHeaderArray(headerLabels2);
    bean2.setDatatypeArray(datatypeArray2);
    bean2.setData(workLists2);

    downloadExcelBean.put("downloadExcelBean", bean);
    downloadExcelBean.put("downloadExcelBean2", bean2);
    return new ModelAndView("DownloadExcelView", "model",
                downloadExcelBean);



}
```

And in DownloadExcelView.java I have build excel document function

```
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map model, HSSFWorkbook workbook,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

    Log.info(DownloadExcelView.class,
            "Execution starts....buildExcelDocument()");

    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");

    Map<String, DownloadExcelBean> exceldownload = (Map<String, DownloadExcelBean>) model.get("model");

    for (Map.Entry<String, DownloadExcelBean> mapobject : exceldownload.entrySet()) 
    {

        DownloadExcelBean obj = (DownloadExcelBean) mapobject.getValue();
        String filename = obj.getFilename(); // File name
        String sheetname = obj.getSheetname(); // sheet Name
        String headerlist[] = obj.getHeaderArray(); // header names
        int dataTypeArray[] = obj.getDatatypeArray();

        List resultsetValues = obj.getData();

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
                + filename + ".xls");

        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetname); // create a sheet
        HSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook.createSheet("Second tab");

        HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = setHeaderStyle(workbook); // Apply bold
                                                            // for header

        HSSFRow header = sheet1.createRow(0); // create a header row

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        short decimalDataformat = workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat(
                "#,###,##0.00");

        HSSFCellStyle decimalCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        decimalCellStyle.setDataFormat(decimalDataformat);
        HSSFCellStyle wrapStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        wrapStyle.setWrapText(true);

        int visibleCol = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < headerlist.length; i++) {

            visibleCol++;
            HSSFCell cell = header.createCell(visibleCol);
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            cell.setCellValue(headerlist[i].replace("<br/>", ARConstants.EXPORT_CRLF));

        }

        // Excel cell values
        HSSFRow hssfrow;
        HSSFCell cell;

        for (int row = 0; row < resultsetValues.size(); row++) {

            List rowList = (ArrayList) resultsetValues.get(row);

            hssfrow = sheet1.createRow(row + 1);
            visibleCol = -1;
            for (int col = 0; col < rowList.size(); col++) {

                // if(visibleArray[col]){
                visibleCol++;
                cell = hssfrow.createCell(visibleCol);

                if (dataTypeArray[col] == java.sql.Types.DECIMAL) {

                    cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                    cell.setCellStyle(decimalCellStyle);

                    if (rowList.get(col) != null)
                        cell.setCellValue((Double) rowList.get(col));
                    else
                        cell.setCellValue("");

                } else if (dataTypeArray[col] == java.sql.Types.DATE) {

                    if (rowList.get(col) != null)
                        cell.setCellValue(dateFormat.format(rowList
                                .get(col)));
                    else
                        cell.setCellValue("");

                }
                else if (dataTypeArray[col] == java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP) {
                    cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    cell.setCellStyle(wrapStyle);


                    if (rowList.get(col) != null)
                        cell.setCellValue(StringUtils.dateToUSFormatDateTimeTillMins(rowList.get(col).toString())
                                .replace(" ", ARConstants.EXPORT_CRLF));
                    else
                        cell.setCellValue("");

                }

                else if (dataTypeArray[col] == java.sql.Types.OTHER)
                {
                    cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    cell.setCellStyle(wrapStyle);
                    String crlf = Character.toString((char) 13)
                            + Character.toString((char) 10);

                    if (rowList.get(col) != null)
                    {
                        String str=(rowList.get(col).toString()).replaceAll("\t","    ");
                        if((str.replace("|", crlf)).length()> 32767)
                            cell.setCellValue((str.replace("|", crlf)).substring(0,32766));
                        else
                            cell.setCellValue(str.replace("|", crlf));
                    }
                    else

                        cell.setCellValue("");

                } 
                else 
                {
                    cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

                    if (rowList.get(col) != null)
                    {
                        String str=(rowList.get(col).toString()).replaceAll("\t","    ");
                        if(str.length() > 32767)
                        {
                            cell.setCellValue(str.substring(0,32766));

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cell.setCellValue(str);

                        }
                    }

                    else
                        cell.setCellValue("");

                }
                // sheet.autoSizeColumn(col);
            }

        }

    }


    Log.info(DownloadExcelView.class,
            "Execution ends....buildExcelDocument()");

}
```